# Re-Calc Lowerd Rep, Then Activity Raised it, Got Max 200, Then Today Back Down

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, rep-recalc

I was somewhat shocked yesterday when the re-calc dropped my rep down ~250 or so (on SU)...  OK, fine.  I read the info and started doing my business.  I hit the max cap of 200 yesterday, after the re-calc, and now today I'm back down again...  Not sure what is going on.  I was under the impression the re-calc would happen and then we could all move forward from there.  Is this not the case?  Are there recurring re-calcs?

What's more...  I even got a mortarboard bronze badge...  So that sort of implies that I did hit the cap.  However, when I go to https://superuser.com/reputation it shows that I never hit the cap, and, in fact, yesterday, I only got 60.  Is it possible that the old calcs were used, and then at some point the new calcs were applied?

I know, I know...  Many people will say, "Who cares, it's about helping others and getting your own questions answered."  OK, I get this and I like this.  But it would be nice if I fully knew how it worked.  For a long time, my rep was steady, growing expectantly.  Now, for the last few days, each time I log in it changes +/- 200 points.

Comment: On Stack Overflow or Super User?  Your account only has 1 rep on SO, and the link to SU goes to a page that doesn't exist.

Comment: Yah, at first I didn't make that distinction, but now it's there (see above)...  Superuser...  Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

There may have been another reputation recalc instigated on your account recently. This can be triggered by a number of factors, such as someone serial upvoted or downvoted you, or you serial upvoted or downvoted someone else, two accounts were merged, etc.  An SU moderator will be able to check and see if this is the case.

At any rate, your reputation report at https://superuser.com/reputation will be the *canonical* record of voting and reputation history on your account. Given that you recall hitting the reputation cap, and now the report only shows a gain of 60 reputation, it's quite possible that some erroneous upvotes were cleaned out by the system.

Comment: OK, that sounds good.  Thanks.  Couple of questions:  What is serial voting (up and/or down) and what are erroneous upvotes?

Comment: @nico: see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=serial+voting -- I've been a victim of it myself.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your Mortarboard badge, here's the relevant snippet from [the official Badge FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work):

> The site admin has stated multiple times that, by design, badges cannot be lost or revoked. There are two exceptions to this rule...

Basically, what happened is:

1. You hit the rep cap at some point before the recalc.
2. The mechanism for awarding badges saw that, and credited you Mortarboard.
3. After the recalc, you dropped below the cap for that day.
4. Since you didn't actively cheat, you get to keep that Mortarboard forever
5. But, the day for which you were awarded that Mortarboard for will **not** count towards the Epic or Legendary badges.

Answer (score 2):

The daily vote anomaly detector has kicked in multiple times on your account; the anomalous votes were removed.

(This is visible to diamond moderators only in your user history.)

You should email team@superuser.com for more detail if you want it.